# Does git have a "relative" treeish?

Tags: git

I'm trying to verify each commit in a sequence, moving from the first to the current tip.  It's not really a `git bisect`, I don't expect any problems and the tip works.  But I want to make sure each commit is self-contained and correct.

I can use HEAD^ to go back one from the tip but is there a "one forward from where I am" treeish? That is, if I have

```
o aaabbbccc (tip)
|
o abcdefabc
|
o fedcbafed
|
o abcdabcde
|
o deadbeefe (root)
```

I want to do:

```
git checkout deadbeefe
build and test
git checkout current+1
<up two, return>
<up two, return>
```

But I can't figure out the treeish for "current+1".

Comment: That's not a "tree-ish". You are talking about commits, not trees (or objects containing trees, such as commits and tags). But no, there is no such way in git to reference a child commit (there could be more than one) and history is only stored with parent pointers, not the other way round. You could use `HEAD~n` and iteratively decrease `~n` though

Comment: @knittl I would add that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git does not store links from parents to children; only links from children to parents.  To find a commit's children, you have to start at the childmost commits in your repository (branch tips, tags, HEAD, etc.) and walk up the chain of parents until you either reach a root node or find the commit in question.

If your commit DAG is linear and `tip` is a reference to the childmost commit, you can do something like the following to find the child commit of revision `deadbeefe`:

```
git rev-list deadbeefe..tip | tail -n 1
```

This causes Git to start walking from `tip` until it reaches `deadbeefe` or the root and print out all the commits it comes across.  The output is then piped to `tail` to select the last visited commit, which will be the child of `deadbeefe` if the commit history is linear.

`HEAD` refers to the currently checked-out commit, so if you need the child of the current commit instead of `deadbeefe`, use `HEAD`.  Commands that require a commit default to `HEAD` if unspecified, so you can do the following:

```
git rev-list ..tip | tail -n 1
```

Again, this only works if the DAG is linear.  If the commit history is not linear, you can use the `--ancestry-path` argument to `rev-list`.

Doing the above each time you want to move to the next commit would be O(n^2), but Git is so fast that it usually doesn't matter in practice.  If you need it to be O(n), I'd do the following:

```
git rev-list --reverse tip | while IFS= read -r rev; do
    git checkout "${rev}" || handle_checkout_error_here
    # build and test here
done
```

And @knittl is correct—the term you want here is commit, not treeish.  Some terminology:

- A 'treeish' is something that can act like a file system tree (e.g., the index, your working directory, a subdirectory in your working directory, a commit, a subdirectory inside a commit, etc.).
- 'Revision' is less well defined than commit, but it usually means the things that identify a commit (commits themselves, annotated tags that point to a commit, and references that refer to a commit).
- A 'reference' is a pointer to a Git object or another reference (in which case it's called a 'symbolic reference').  A reference usually points to a commit or annotated tag object, but it can point to anything.  People usually say reference when they want to generically refer to `HEAD`, tags, and/or branches.

Comment: Thanks for making it clear that what I want to do isn't directly possible and providing a technique to work around that.

I don't really want a loop like you show because I may do this one at a time, go to a meeting, etc.

If git doesn't have a way to say "where I am +/- n commits", is there at least a way to say "where am I"?  That is, if I say, `git checkout deadbeefe`, what can I insert into `git ???` to get back "deadbeefe"?  If I had that, I coudl use yourr `tail` technique outside a loop.

Comment: As for the `treeish`, I know I'm trying to manipulate commits but I was trying to distinguish between using SHAs explicitly and using something like HEAD, branch{n}, etc.  What's the generic name for such symbolic references to commits?

Comment: @ChrisNelson, expressions like `HEAD^^` and `origin/master~4` are called [ancestry references](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#_ancestry_references).